# WebAPI, Unity, & Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am trying to use Unity in my WebAPI solution and I am trying to load the configuration from web.config file.

This is unity section in web.config:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <assembly name="MyWebAPI" />
  <namespace name="MyWebAPI.Controllers" />
  <container>
    <register type="MyController" mapTo="MyController">
      <constructor>
        <param name="param1">
          <value value="val1" />
        </param>
        <param name="param2">
          <value value="val2" />
        </param>
        <param name="param3">
          <value value="val3" />
        </param>
      </constructor>
      <lifetime type="singleton" />
    </register>
  </container>  
</unity>
```

The Bootstrapper.cs:

```
public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
{
  var container = BuildUnityContainer();

  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

  return container;
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
  var container = new UnityContainer();

  // register all your components with the container here
  // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

  // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();    
  RegisterTypes(container);

  return container;
}

public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<MyController>();  
    container.LoadConfiguration();
}
```

The Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();  
    }
```

But this is not working for me as the parameter is not getting into the constructor.

The WebAPI controller constructor:

```
    public MyController(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        _param1 = param1;
        _param2 = param2;
        _param3 = param3;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of MVC DependencyResolver, use the Web API specific GlobalConfiguration resolver.  e.g.:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

If you use the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/) this gets set up for you on installation.

Comment: I tried that...I changed the code to be GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container); but now I am getting this error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

For Web Api, where your controllers are based on the ApiController class you should use:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

This means that

```
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

is used to register Unity as a Dependency Resolver for the MVC side of your application.

(You can have both statements if you like to register Unity for both MVC and WebApi)

If you get the System.Web.Http versions error, then try deleting the System.Web.Http.dll from your references and remove Unit.WebApi.
Then re-add Unity.WebAPI.5.1 Nuget package and it should be fine.